# Is it possible to get terminal notifications in OSX through a docker container?

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, libnotify

For instance, `libnotify` sends file events through a specific port (I don't remember which one).

1. Is it an event send on a specific port? In which case I would guess it would be possible for a linux container to send an event to the host OSX development machine.
2. It connects, or calls a OSX command, which is likely only available on the host OSX machine.

Anyone have insights on this?

Comment: Push from container sounds intriguing. A pull mechanism could work via a technique from this gist: https://gist.github.com/prebenlm/5562656 See part 3. Have a container that does your particular action, and then log the things you want to STDOUT, and use this in a script to send the messages it sees via terminal-notifier

Comment: Another technique suggested here: https://superuser.com/questions/645036/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-from-a-remote-terminal-in-os-x is where you just have the container ssh back to the host and use terminal-notifier with the message of your choice